# what does exactly the function barrier do in GLSL?

Tags: opengl, glsl, compute-shader, barrier, workgroup

I am reading a small github project, within which there is a compute shader code to organize an index buffer of indirect draw call as follows,

```
layout(local_size_x=1024, local_size_y=1, local_size_z=1) in;

/* some stuffs */

void main()
{
    uint id = gl_GlobalInvocationID.x; //for grass blade

    if(id == 0)
    {
        atomicExchange(indirect[0], 0);
    }

    barrier();
    
    if(id < 10240)
    {
        /* do some stuffs like
        if(culled)
        {
            return;
        }
        */
    
        uint index = atomicAdd(indirect[0], 1);
        ind[index] = id;
    }
}
```

with a dispatch call as follows,

```
glDispatchCompute(11, 1, 1);
```

I am confused because as I learned from [OpenGL Refpage](https://registry.khronos.org/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/barrier.xhtml),

> For any given static instance of `barrier` in a compute shader, all invocations **within a single work group** must enter it before any are allowed to continue beyond it.

the barrier function only synchronize all invocations within a single work group, which, if I understand it correctly, says here only the `1024 * 1 * 1`  invocations will synchronize with each other.

Since we dispatch 11 work groups here, there are 11 synchronizations within each group, though the order of executions between these 11 work groups is undefined.

Now assume that the invocation with `id == 2048` run so fast that it executes

```
uint index = atomicAdd(indirect[0], 1);
```

before the invocation with `id == 0` have executed

```
atomicExchange(indirect[0], 0);
```

( Again if I understand it correctly, this could happen because they are not in the same work group. So the barrier function cannot synchronize them.)

then the invocation with `id == 2048` may reach an uninitialized value of `indirect[0]` ; Or even `indirect[0] == 0`  at the very first time, there will be a confliction `ind[0] == 2048`  and `ind[0] == i != 2048`  where `i`  is the id of a certain invocation which is the first invocation to execute

```
uint index = atomicAdd(indirect[0], 1);
```

after

```
atomicExchange(indirect[0], 0);atomicExchange(indirect[0], 0);
```

has been executed.

I was wondering where did I go wrong.

Did I misunderstand the function `barrier` ? Maybe it synchronize globally all invocations with a dispatch?

Or Did I misunderstand the concept of  `work group`?

Comment: barrier only synchronizes threads in the same workgroup, exactly like you said. You are correct that this is a problem in this code. Since you took that from a random repository, there is a non-zero chance that the code is simply wrong.

Comment: Read this portion of the OpenGL wiki.  https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Compute_Shader  The `local_size_x=1024` defines the number compute shader invocations within each of the working groups.  So all 1024 x 1 x 1 invocations will pause at the memory barrier.  Yet the 11 working groups will all act independently without checking for each other.  From the doc "if the local size of a compute shader is (128, 1, 1), and you execute it with a work group count of (16, 8, 64), then you will get 1,048,576 separate shader invocations."